# Envers adding user information

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I got a problem with Envers. At first, here are my two hibernate classes:

child.java:

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class child {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String text;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="child")
    private testclass parent;
    public int getId() {return id;}
    public void setId(int id) {this.id = id;}
    public String getText() {return text;}
    public void setText(String text) {this.text = text;}
    public testclass getParent() {return parent;}
    public void setParent(testclass parent) {this.parent = parent;}
}
```

testclass.java:

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class testclass {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq_template")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="seq_template", sequenceName="tester_seq")
    private int id;

    private String text;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
    private Set<child> childs;

    public int getId() {return id;}
    public void setId(int id) {this.id = id;}
    public String getText() {return text;}
    public void setText(String text) {this.text = text;}
    public Set<child> getChilds() {return childs;}
    public void setChilds(Set<child> childs) {this.childs = childs;}
}
```

Both classes are working fine and the audit information, like timestamp is stored well.

I want to extend now the information with the audit information username. For that I created these configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="ch.triwdata.envers.extensions">
    <class name="ExtendedRevisionEntity" table="revinfo">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="rev" not-null="true"/>
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="timestamp" type="long" column="timestamp" />
        <property name="username" type="string" not-null="true"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

there is of course also a configuration file with hibernate-configuration, but I don't think that this is important here.

Could anybody see my failure, why the userinformation are not stored?

Best regards
Björn

PS:
Maybe this xml is missing? I've added it of course since begining:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.password">****</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>

        <mapping class="testclass"/>
        <mapping class="child"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: are you getting any exception or something, can you post over here?

Comment: eclipse says that:
ERROR: 3:60 Element type "hibernate-mapping" must be declared.
ERROR: 4:55 Element type "class" must be declared.
ERROR: 5:34 Element type "id" must be declared.
ERROR: 6:40 Element type "column" must be declared.
ERROR: 7:31 Element type "generator" must be declared.
ERROR: 9:69 Attribute "type" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR: 9:69 Attribute "column" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR: 10:60 Attribute "type" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR: 10:60 Attribute "not-null" must be declared for element type "property".

Comment: Ok, that issue I have fixed... But table didn't create the column, with the username. It's running without a issue, but didn't create the column username.

Comment: I have added some more informations to my previous post.

Comment: try after modifying mapping file to `<property name="username" type="java.lang.String" not-null="true"/>`

Comment: Hey Amogh, thanks, but it didn't make any result. Best regards Björn

Comment: Hey Is your DB is already created? and in hibernate configuration what is value of `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property. will try setting it to `update` or `create` if possible.

Comment: I got it, take a look to my reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it! :D

The failure was here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">twd_genmeta</property>
<!--         <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver</property> -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.password">Deliaa</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>

        <mapping class="ch.triwdata.envers.classes.testclass"/>
        <mapping class="ch.triwdata.envers.classes.child"/>
        <mapping resource="hibernate.hbm.xml"/> <---- this entry is missing
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Thanks a lot for your reply!

Best regards
Björn

Comment: Gr8 :) congratulations